# Connection Timeout when idSMTP when using TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, indy10

I'm having a problem using **TidSMTP** with **TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL** getting **"Socket Error"** just by connecting to the server.

Here's the Form Component Code

```
  object IdSMTP: TIdSMTP
    IOHandler = IdSSLIOHandlerSSL
    Port = 465
    SASLMechanisms = <>
    UseTLS = utUseImplicitTLS
    Left = 93
    Top = 49
  end
  object IdSSLIOHandlerSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    OnStatus = IdSSLIOHandlerSSLStatus
    Destination = ':465'
    MaxLineAction = maException
    Port = 465
    DefaultPort = 0
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    OnStatusInfo = IdSSLIOHandlerSSLStatusInfo
    Left = 88
    Top = 112
  end
```

and Delphi Code

```
 IdSMTP.Username  := 'username';
 IdSMTP.Password  := 'password';
 IdSMTP.Host      := 'domain';
 IdSMTP.Port      := 465;
 IdSMTP.UseTLS    := utUseImplicitTLS;
 try
    IdSMTP.Connect;
 except
    on E:Exception do
       // Socket Error, Connection Timeout is thrown.
       Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
 end;
```

I logged SSL IO status and got this:

```
Resolving hostname {domain}.
Connecting to {ip}.
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
Socket Error # 10060
Connection timed out.
```

Our mail server is using self-signed certificate by the way.

What am i doing wrong?

TIA

**UPDATE:07-02-2014**

Tried [Sending mail to Gmail using Indy](http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html) tip but i get **Connection Closed Gracefully** sending the email also after **SSLv3 read server hello A**.

```
Resolving hostname smtp.gmail.com.
Connecting to 74.125.25.108.
Connected.
Sending Email..
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
Disconnected.
Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Here's the new code:

```
 IdSMTP.Username  := 'username';
 IdSMTP.Password  := 'password';
 IdSMTP.Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
 IdSMTP.UseTLS    := utUseExplicitTLS;
 IdSMTP.Port      := 587;
 try
    // Can connect successfully
    IdSMTP.Connect;

    // This part throws the exception
    IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
 except
    on E:Exception do
       // Disconnected, connection closed gracefully 
       Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
 end;
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried sending email using Thunderbird connecting to same domain.

Thunderbird:
[image: Wireshark capture - Sending email using thunderbird]

Indy:
[image: Wireshark capture - Using Indy]

No "**client key exchange, ...**" occurred on my program.

**SOLVED**

This isssue was resolved by Manually setting connectiontimeout

Answer (score 3):

You are using implicit SSL.  That means an SSL handshake is initiated as soon as the socket is connected to the server, before any application data (SMTP commands/responses) are exchanged.  A client hello is sent to the server, and then a timeout is occurring while waiting for the server to send back a hello in response.  That implies that the server is NOT using SSL on the port you are connecting to.

Something to keep in mind - setting the `UseTLS` property may change the `Port` property, so make sure the `Port` is actually what you are expecting when `Connect()` is called.  To make sure, try setting the `Port` after setting the `UseTLS` rather than before.

Comment: the timeout/socket error occurs right after server hello, no additional delay. the connection is abruptly terminated.

Comment: the port is using SSL because we can send email using other mail clients like Thunderbird. Putting port assignment after setting UseTLS also have the same result.

Comment: An immediate disconnect likely means Gmail is rejecting the handshake. Have you tried using a packet sniffer to look at the handshake messages? Also, when connecting to Gmail, did you set the `SSLVersion` to TLSv1? Don't use SSLv3.

Comment: i'm using v1 only. Sniffed using wireshark and found out client Key Exchange don't occur when using Indy (we're using Self-Signed Certificate). I'll see how i can exchange keys with our Server.

Comment: Your client is closing the socket (sending a `FIN` TCP packet) after receiving the server hello. Either OpenSSL is rejecting the server's certificate, or an exception is being raised, or the like.

Comment: Does Indy automatically handle this? Is there a way to override this? I tried assigning `OnVerifyPeer` but it's not called.

Comment: Indy raises an exception if the handshake fails. If that happens within `Connect()`, Indy closes the socket.

Comment: Any news for this issue ? I'm having the exactly same problem, but only in Delphi XE. On the same machine / configs in Delphi 2007, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your firewall is temporarily disabled.
I got to this page because I was having the same problem - immediate disconnection with "Connection closed gracefully" when doing SMTP with SSL.
Then I disabled my Avast! firewall and it was fine.